# Android centering multiple layouts horizontally

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to find out how to center a layout between a layout that is centered horizontally and the parent edge.

What I have is a custom view. I want to place 5 of these views centered horizontally at the top(I have been able to do this no problem). I'll call this centered_layout. Then on each side of centered_layout I would like a left_layout and right_layout centered in the remaining space between the edge and center_layout, with 2 more of these views and a label. I have been able to do this but not centered.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you paste the code that you have so far? the xml code

Comment: You should add a image to describe your request more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you have in mind? I used `TextViews` instead of your own custom views. This should work as long as the sum of the widths of your views is not bigger than the screen width.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-B"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-A"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="A"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="B"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="C"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="D"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="E"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="F"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="G"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @NT This is what I was looking for. I see now its the weight/width combination. I did some searching on weight and 0dp width and now I understand better what is going on. Thanks.